# Long int too large to convert to float

Tags: python, casting

Assuming I have a program with the function

```
def fakultaet(x):
    if x>1:
        return(x* fakultaet(x-1)) 
    else:
        return(1)
```

that returns the factorial of a given number, I need to calculate

```
1.0/fakultaet(200)
```

but I get an overflow error: `long int too large to convert to float`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Style note: `return` is a statement, not a function, and thus you don't usually write parentheses around the returned object. You'd write `return x * fakultaet(x-1)` and `return 1` instead. See for instance a random example from the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def fakultaet(x):  # as you have it currently
    if x>1:
        return(x * fakultaet(x-1)) 
    else:
        return(1)

print Decimal(1.0) / fakultaet(200)
```

Output:

```
1.267976953480962421753016371E-375
```

---

Oh, and also, there is a `factorial` function in the `math` module already, just include `from math import factorial` at the top of your file to obtain access to it.

Comment: This is a ridiculously small number, because 200! is a ridiculously large number. :)

Comment: @hobbs Exactly, that's why you need to use to use the `Decimal` class explicitly (you can't just sort it out with `float`s).

Comment: Indeed, if the OP was able to use floats, he'd probably end up with 0 in the end anyways.